# Why am I receiving undefined types for imported packages in PHP?

Tags: php, encryption, aes

I'm using [Spomky Labs' JWT Framework Library](https://web-token.spomky-labs.com/) v3.0 for PHP to create [JWE Tokens](https://web-token.spomky-labs.com/the-components/encrypted-tokens-jwe).

I've ran `composer require web-token/jwt-encryption` to install the library in my PHP project. Here's my `composer.json`

```
{
    "require": {
        "web-token/jwt-encryption": "^3.0",
        "web-token/jwt-core": "^3.0"
    }
}
```

When I start importing the different namespaces - for example the Encryption Algorithms namespace:

```
<?php

require_once realpath("vendor/autoload.php");

use Jose\Component\Encryption\Algorithm\KeyEncryption\A256KW;
use Jose\Component\Encryption\Algorithm\ContentEncryption\A256CBCHS512;

?>
```

VSCode PHP IntelliSense does not show any error.

But when I start using these namespaces, IntelliSense starts showing an error of

> Undefined type '*insert namespace here*'

Example:

[image: IntelliSense Error]

Here is my folder structure:

```
XAMPP/
├─ htdocs/
│  ├─ encryption_project/
│  │  ├─ index.php
│  │  ├─ composer.lock
│  │  ├─ composer.json
│  │  ├─ vendor/
│  │  │  ├─ autoload.php
│  │  │  ├─ web-token/
│  │  │  │  ├─ jwt-encryption/
│  │  │  │  ├─ jwt-core/
```

---

I'm using XAMPP (Apache Web Server) to run my PHP code and editing in VSCode.

My OS is MacOS Monterey. My PHP version is 8.1.6

Comment: jwt-encryption is not enough. You have to add others library. Take a look there : https://web-token.spomky-labs.com/the-components/algorithm-management-jwa

Comment: Hi @svgta I installed the `web-token/jwt-core` library but it still displays the error unfortunately. I added an image of the errors on the post for reference.

Comment: This library is honestly a little confusing compared to other ones I've used online. It isn't super-obvious looking at just the code that things are broken up into a bunch of subcomponents. For instance, [this page shows the Algorithms packages](https://web-token.spomky-labs.com/the-components/signed-tokens-jws/signature-algorithms) you can optionally install, and [this one has the Encryption packages](https://web-token.spomky-labs.com/the-components/encrypted-tokens-jwe/encryption-algorithms)

Comment: @ChrisHaas It definitely can get confusing. May I know some of the PHP libraries you've used for JWE Tokens?

Comment: That library is great as far as I know, and I'm not recommending that you stop using it in anyway. It is just that they broke things up into many components and you need to read the documentation a little more thoroughly than other libraries (IMHO). That said, JWT is opposed by many people, partly because developers didn't read and/or understand the documentation, so maybe that's a good thing. I personally use `lcobucci/jwt`

Comment: Hi @dale, can you open an issue? I would like to understand what is going on. Many thanks https://github.com/web-token/jwt-framework/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Bug&projects=&template=1_Bug_report.yaml